# Force hibernate to leave id empty

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

So I am using Postgres and Hibernate 4.2.2 and with entity like this

```
@Entity(name = "Users")
@Check(constraints = "email ~* '^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+$'")
@DynamicInsert
public class Users {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id_user",unique = true)
  @Index(name = "user_pk")
  private Integer idUser;
```

Hibernate still inserts some id that is already in the table, instead of leaving it emtpy for the database to fill it in. Also hibernate forces ids based on its cache not even checking the database whether it has the lates id.

How can I force it so I can leave id blank and let the database insert it?

First I thought it was because I was using `int` and that `int` is by default 0 but even when using object it just forces the id there from its cache.

So my goal is to let the database fill the ids instead of hibernate or at least Hibernate before filling it in to check the database for id first.

Comment: show us the code that you use to insert your entity

Comment: OK so the mistake here was, that when inserting into Postgres without using the sequence (improting data on databse creation) the sequence stays still without incrementing and that was the error

Comment: post it as an answer to your question

Comment: you need to reset your sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the error I was getting was
`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey" Detail: Key (id_user)=(1) already exists.`
And it wasn't caused by Hibernate and caching but by import of data at creation of database, where I inserted with given ids eg:
 `INSERT INTO users(id_user,email,password,tag) VALUES (1,'a@b.c','***','Adpleydu');`
and the sequence for generating wasn't updated so if I inserted with pure SQL via console I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Seeding the data is the problem. However you can still seed with pure sequal and have the sequence "keep up".

1) Assure your primary key is of type SERIAL.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
    id SERIAL
);
```

2) Add this 'setval' line to assure the sequence is updated.

```
select setval('table_name_id_seq',COALESCE((select max(id) + 1 from table_name), 1));
```

#### Reference:

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/